# Hide multiple row on click of check box

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik-grid

I am trying to hide two colomn on check of checkbox i used telerk  radgrid control for it. grid contains five colomn ID ,FName , LName,MobileNo,branch .When check box is checked on want to hide ID and name colomn please give hint for that  my code is as follow

C# code:
 class MainWindowViewModel
    {

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        EmpList = ListOfEmpInfo();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<EmpInfo> ListOfEmpInfo()
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<EmpInfo>()
       {
           new EmpInfo(){ ID=1, City ="Pune" , FirstName ="Rahul" , LasttName ="Rathod", MobileNumber =123},
            new EmpInfo(){ ID=2, City ="Mumbai" , FirstName ="Mahesh" , LasttName ="Yogaa", MobileNumber =456},
             new EmpInfo(){ID=3, City ="Jalna" , FirstName ="Ganesh" , LasttName ="Kapadia", MobileNumber =178923}



       };





    }
    public ObservableCollection<EmpInfo> EmpList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


}

<Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="Hide Show"  IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}"  Height="40"  Grid.Column="2"></CheckBox>
               <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding EmpList}"
                         Grid.Column="1" 
                         Margin="10,0,0,0" />

    </Grid>
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your goal?  What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: On check of checkbox  i want to hide ID and name colomns of radgridview

Comment: I understand what you want to do.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a working solution here: [WPF Control TabItem visibility from a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990982/wpf-control-tabitem-visibility-from-a-checkbox)

Of course, in your case, you will need to name your checkbox with an x:Name and use it like so:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="150" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=chk,Converter={StaticResource b2v}}"/>
```

Just in case the other link is not available, here is the StaticResource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
</Window.Resources>
```