# WPF XAML: Quickly hide rows of a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, a database is filled with personal data.
Among them is if a person is alive, and if not, date and place of their death can be given. Where you can feed the data, I have a grid with two columns, in the left one is "place of death" text block, in the right is a TextBox. Same for date of death.
If you select the "Alive" check box, I tried hiding both TextBlocks and TextBoxes with a style trigger and Visibility.Collapsed setter inside them, which seems really inconvenient.

Is there any other approach to do this?

Comment: Are you using MVVM ?

Comment: Can't you just leave them empty if a person is alive? Btw, storing this kind of information can be subject to local regulations and law.

Comment: No need for MVVM. You can bind the `Visibility` property of your TestBlocks to the `IsChecked` property of your 'alive' checkbox. using the build in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`. See [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6991052/4634044)

Comment: @ChristianMurschall I didn't say it was needed I just asked if he was using it.

Comment: Filter the DataGrid in the Checked and Unchecked event handlers (or using a command if you are using MVVM)?

Comment: @Stefan thank you for the information. I will keep that in mind

Comment: @ChristianMurschall thank you, excellent approach. Would have ticked it as correct if it wasn't a comment but an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVVM , you can bind the Visibility to a boolean and use a value converter to change it to collapsed.

Look for BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the Height of Row to achieve your goal.
XAML

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyGrid">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="60" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="80" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind: C#

```
MyGrid.RowDefinitions(2).Height = new GridLength(0);
```

Code Behind: VB.NET

```
MyGrid.RowDefinitions(2).Height = New GridLength(0)
```